# Variable for docker repository inside docker-compose.yaml

Tags: docker, docker-compose

Is there any way to have a variable inside `docker-compose.yaml` for docker repository name? Or any other way of declaring repository outside of image name?

I have a few docker containers in AWS ECR repos and docker-compose file contains several declarations like:

```
image: <account>.dkr.ecr.<region>.amazonaws.com/<image>:latest
```

and I would like to declare only once `<account>.dkr.ecr.<region>.amazonaws.com` to minimize changes required for deployment in other account or moving images to other repository.

Many thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can define it in `.env` file in the same folder than your docker-compose.yaml

**.env**

```
ACCOUNT=myaccount
REGION=myregion
IMAGE=niceimage
VERSION=latest
```

**docker-compose.yaml**

```
...
image: ${ACCOUNT}.dkr.ecr.${REGION}.amazonaws.com/${IMAGE}:${VERSION}
```

You don't need to specify env_file = .env unless you need .env variables inside docker.